# Establishing relationship between two entities?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have names of events in a tableview and I like to save responses(yes = 1, no = 2 from action controller) of user along with event name. So I created 2 entities

```
EventSchedule (eventName: String, eventTime: Transformable)
```

with `one to one` relationship `eventSchedule` to

`EventDec (eventStatus: Integer16)`

and `one to one` inverse relationship `eventDec`

I did the following

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes", style: .default) { _ in

let eventDesc = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventDec", into: context)
let eventSch = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventSchedule", into: context)

//How do I add relationship property to the above objects so that I can store event name along with response in database?

            eventDesc.setValue(1, forKey: "eventStatus")
            do
            {
                try context.save()
                print("Record Saved Successfully")
                print(eventDesc)
            }
            catch{}
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .default) { _ in

 let eventDesc = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventDec", into: context)
    let eventSch = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventSchedule", into: context)

//How do I add relationship property to the above objects so that I can store event name along with response in database?

            eventDesc.setValue(2, forKey: "eventStatus")
            do
            {
                try context.save()
                print("Record Saved Successfully")
                print(eventDesc)
            }
            catch{} 
        })

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You can set relation with KVC same as you are inserting the data `eventDesc.setValue(2, forKey: "eventStatus")`. You have to use relationship name there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `didSelectRowAt` with the following one (based on discussion in chat):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let eventDesc = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventDec", into: context) as! EventDec
    var eventSch: EventSchedule?
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventSchedule")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventName == %@", self.eventTitle)
        var objects: [EventSchedule]

        try objects = context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [EventSchedule]
        eventSch = objects[0] as EventSchedule
        print(eventSch)

    } catch {
        print("whatever")
    }

    eventSch.eventDec = eventDesc
    eventDesc.eventSchedule = eventSch

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes", style: .default) { _ in
        eventDesc.setValue(1, forKey: "eventStatus")

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch{
            print("Try again")
        }
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .default) { _ in
        eventDesc.setValue(2, forKey: "eventStatus")

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Try again")
        }
    })
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// ... Your code...

let eventDesc = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventDec", into: context)

// insert eventDesc into coredata
eventDesc.setValue(2, forKey: "eventStatus")

// relation & inverse relation
eventSch.eventDec = eventDesc
eventDesc.eventSchedule = eventSch

// rest of your code, as is...
```

Let me know, how it goes.

---

**EDIT**

You can get the `eventSch` object like following:

```
do {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EventSchedule")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", your_event_name)
    var objects: [EventSchedule]

    // objects[0] is your object here.
    try objects = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [EventSchedule]

} catch {
    print("whatever")
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response, I populate eventSch values in another viewController. So do I need to create "relation_key" and "inverse_relation_key" attributes with type "Integer"  as it says "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'relation_key' after executing your code?

Comment: If you are creating it in another viewcontroller, then you need to fetch THAT particular `eventSch` object for the above code to work. You are creating a new `eventSch` object. That's why it's not working.

Comment: Ok. I will fetch it and try. What about the relationship. Do I need to create any special attributes to establish the relationship?

Comment: No. You don't need any. You can get the relation and inverse relation name/key from your `.momd` file, where you have defined it.

Comment: Appreciate it your response, will let you know shortly once I try this

Comment: I am getting these 2 errors  "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'relation_key'  and   "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'inverse_relation_key'

Comment: You need to check the `.momd` file for your relation & inverse relation key. Can you show us your `.momd` file or may be a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136715/discussion-between-coder221-and-ios-app-dev).

Comment: Thanks for your help.